# Spring bean depends on mule endpoint

Tags: spring, tcp, mule, lifecycle, endpoint

I have a bean in Mule that needs to send a message before a TCP endpoint is disconnected on shutdown. The bean implements Lifecycle and is configured with "depends-on=connector," but it seems like the "depends-on" has no effect on the shutdown order. The endpoint is no longer connected when the stop method is called on my bean. Is there a way for the "stop" method to be called on my bean before it is called on the endpoint or connector? I'm using Mule 3.7 CE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to listen to the MuleContextNotification and wait for a CONTEXT_STOPPING action to trigger your TCP call.

See example below:

```
public class MuleContextListener implements MuleContextNotificationListener<MuleContextNotification>,MuleContextAware {

    private MuleContext context;
    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MuleContextListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onNotification(MuleContextNotification notification) {
        logger.info("NOTIFICATION RECEIVED!!!!!");
        logger.info(MuleContextNotification.getActionName(notification.getAction()));
        if(notification.getAction() == MuleContextNotification.CONTEXT_STOPPING ){
            //replace with your tcp call 
            logger.info(" MY ACTION HAS BEEN TRIGGER");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setMuleContext(MuleContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

For testing I have another bean that that implements lifecycle Stoppable...

```
public class ClassStopLc implements Stoppable {

    @Override
    public void stop() throws MuleException {
        logger.info(" ClassStopLC Stopping");
    }
```

If I check my logs:

```
2017-03-22 16:08:26,827 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  mulecontextaware.MuleContextListener - NOTIFICATION RECEIVED!!!!!
2017-03-22 16:08:26,827 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  mulecontextaware.MuleContextListener - mule context stopping
2017-03-22 16:08:26,827 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  mulecontextaware.MuleContextListener -  MY ACTION HAS BEEN TRIGGER
.
.
.
2017-03-22 16:08:32,077 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  org.mule.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager - Stopping ResourceManager
2017-03-22 16:08:32,077 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  org.mule.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager - Stopped ResourceManager
2017-03-22 16:08:32,080 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  mulecontextaware.ClassStopLc -  ClassStopLC Stopping
2017-03-22 16:08:32,082 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  mulecontextaware.MuleContextListener - NOTIFICATION RECEIVED!!!!!
2017-03-22 16:08:32,082 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  mulecontextaware.MuleContextListener - mule context stopped
2017-03-22 16:08:32,083 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  mulecontextaware.MuleContextListener - NOTIFICATION RECEIVED!!!!!
2017-03-22 16:08:32,083 [[mulecontextaware].mulecontextawareFlow.1.02] INFO  mulecontextaware.MuleContextListener - mule context disposing
```

Not sure if the stopping stage will allow you to make the TCP call without any problem, could you try and let me know? I am quite curious :)

Comment: Implementing MuleContextNotificationListener solved the problem. Looking at the mule source code for 3.7, it is due to the order components are shutdown. Starting with line 61 of org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextStopPhase, objects are shutdown in the following order: FlowConstruct, Model, Agent, Connector, Config, QueueManager, and finally Stoppable.

[link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule/mule-core/3.7.0/org/mule/lifecycle/phases/MuleContextStopPhase.java)

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify which lifecycle your Bean is implementing ? Also, Is this a singleton Bean or prototype  Bean?

According to documentation -- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/developing-components#component-lifecycle

You could implement the interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable and just with the method onCall, trigger any operation.

Example:

```
   public class MyClass implements Callable {

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    //DO SOMETHING
    //Call STOP method
    return eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
}}
```

Comment: The bean is a singleton and implements org.mule.api.lifecycle.Lifecycle. On shutdown, mule calls stop() on my class as expected but I need it to be called before stop() is called on the connector so I can send a message before the connector's endpoint is disconnected.